# jquery mobile, pgaechange and pageload not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use ajax to load sometag , but my appended code is not being enhanced by JQM. 
I tried `$(this).trigger('create')` and `$(this).trigger('updatelayout')` but It still not working.

Then I tried to call ajax by function jquery mobile support: $.mobile.changePage()

my code:

```
$.mobile.changePage({url:'/', data:'add_new_tag=true', type:'GET'}, 'slide', false, true)
```

in action index: I render 'index.html'
I have checked it in firebug and see response is right (expected) . But I see nothing change in my browser.

Did I miss something ? I hope to recieve your help . Thank you :D

Comment: What version of jquery mobile are you using?

Comment: I using    jquery-1.6.4.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js

Comment: Your issue was that you were using syntax for old versions but using the code for a new version. Check-out the docs for the `changePage()` function to see how you can pass all options in a single object: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.2/docs/api/methods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never been able to get the trigger('create') method to work for me either. Maybe someone else *cough (Jasper) can help me out with that part of the answer. I may be able to help you with your changPage code though.

Try this for changePage instead:

```
$.mobile.changePage( '/',{ 
    data: "add_new-tag=true",
    type: "get",
    transition: "slide"
});
```

Comment: that 's work . Why my code not run 0_0 .
ah, but the url is change : localhost:3000/getmoreproduct?productlastid=6
is it have way to hide it.

Comment: And script of this action is disable , I try to change bind -> live, but still not working

Comment: Try using 'post' instead of 'get'. Also be sure you are binding to pageinit instead of using dom ready.

Comment: Yes , my script is in pageinit
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#indexPage").live('pageinit',function(){
           $(window).scroll(function(){
                   ....
            $.mobile.changePage( '/getmoreproduct',{
              data: "productlastid=6",
              type: "post",
              transition: "slide"
            });
        });
        

      });
    </script>

Comment: Is your rails code supposed to do something with that data? I don't know much about rails so I can't help you there. Good luck though!

Comment: Thank you so much :D
it work fine now,
But I have annother question, how to ajax 1 part of page by changepage :D